# In Eclipse, how can I figure out how many executable lines of code I have?

Tags: eclipse, line-numbers

I wrote a fairly large program using Eclipse. I'd like to brag a bit about my 920 lines of code, but that's not a realistic number. Is there a way I can figure out the total number of executable lines (ignoring carriage return, comments, and perhaps brackets)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Eclipse plugin like [Metrics2](http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/) (see [Metrics](http://metrics.sourceforge.net/) for older version) for that.

As stated on the Metrics2 page:

> *The project was first initiated by Frank Sauer, but since there was no
>   update for latest JDK and Eclipse, I've decided to Fork and update the
>   project. I would like to thank Frank for all the work he did by
>   starting this. The discontinued project can be found here.*

There is also [CodePro AnalytiX](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-codepro) that I heard of, but actually never tested, so cannot say much about it.